# Grav form redirection

Tags: grav

**Dear stackoverflowers,**

on the site iam currently developing there is a contact form on each subpage – form included from the `/contact` subpage.

Iam able to send the form on each site, but it includes the `/thankyou` page in the `content` block and replaces the main content of the site. So iam still on `/home` page for example.

Now i want to redirect to `/contact` when submitting – so that the `/thankyou` page replaces the `/contact` content.

I tried to add `- redirect: '/contact'` to the form markdown file. But that just redirects me to `/contact`and not submitting the form to the server.

***Any ideas?***

I used that [form Example](https://learn.getgrav.org/forms/forms/example-form) from the [Grav Documentation](https://learn.getgrav.org/forms/forms/example-form) and that [twig file](https://github.com/getgrav/grav-plugin-form/blob/develop/templates/formdata.html.twig) for displaying the thankyou message.

Thank you guys.
Karl

Comment: Please include the header of the form page.

Comment: @Jacobm011 the header of the form page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my problem.

add `action: '/contact'` to the form and also leave the `process: - display: '/thankyou`.

What happens is that it first redirects to `/contact` and includes `/thankyou` afterwards.

The only negative thing is that, when the validation fails, it still redirects you to `/contact`. But i think that is unsolvable.